# Can't find S3 LifecycleTagPredicate in .net sdk for tag based configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, s3-lifecycle-policy

I want to apply S3 LifecycleConfiguration from .net SDK for below criteria

1. Prefix, e.g. "tempdocs/"
2. Tag with its value, e.g { "OneDayExpiry" : "true" }

I'm referring this documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html

I can't find option for applying tag by `LifecycleTagPredicate`, which can consider Tag for LifeCycleRule to delete S3 files

Here is sample rule, where I can only apply expiry days and prefix, but can't find property for Tags

```
var lifeCycleConfiguration = new LifecycleConfiguration()
{
    Rules = new List<LifecycleRule>
    {
        new LifecycleRule
        {
             Id = "Delete one day old objects",
             Filter = new LifecycleFilter()
             {
                 LifecycleFilterPredicate = new LifecyclePrefixPredicate()
                 {
                     Prefix = "tempdocs/"
                 }
             },
             Status = LifecycleRuleStatus.Enabled,
             Expiration = new LifecycleRuleExpiration()
             {
                   Days = 1
             }
        }
    }
};
```

I can see tag property as `LifecycleTagPredicate` in Java and node SDK as below, but can't find this in .Net SDK

```
JAVA SDK

BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule rule2 = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule()
            .withId("Archive and then delete rule")
            .withFilter(new LifecycleFilter(new LifecycleTagPredicate(new Tag("archive", "true"))))
            .addTransition(new Transition().withDays(30).withStorageClass(StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess))
            .addTransition(new Transition().withDays(365).withStorageClass(StorageClass.Glacier))
            .withExpirationInDays(3650)
            .withStatus(BucketLifecycleConfiguration.ENABLED);
```

Do we have any way to create Rule for specific tag in .Net Core SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS documentation for .net https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html does not have updated example for LifeCycle rule, and certain properties are deprecated.

After looking at AWS SDK code for .net and referring to @rlhagerm's answer, Found that as part of Visitor pattern implementation of `LifeCycleRule`, `LifecycleFilterPredicate` can take multiple values like `Prefix` and `Tag`, where both will be part of same `Operands` for given Rule

by this we can create single rule which can suffice both `Prefix` and `Tag` to create policy to auto delete files.

```
var rule = new LifecycleRule
{
    Id = "FileExpiryDaysRule",
    Filter = new LifecycleFilter()
    {
        LifecycleFilterPredicate = new LifecycleAndOperator
        {
            Operands = new List<LifecycleFilterPredicate>
            {
                new LifecyclePrefixPredicate()
                {
                    Prefix = "tempdocs/"
                },
                new LifecycleTagPredicate()
                {
                    Tag = new Amazon.S3.Model.Tag { Key = "OneDayExpiry", Value = "true" },
                }
            }
        }
    },
    Status = LifecycleRuleStatus.Enabled,
    Expiration = new LifecycleRuleExpiration() { Days = 1 },
};

var bucketLifecycleConfiguration = new LifecycleConfiguration
{
    Rules = new List<LifecycleRule>
    {
        { rule }
    }
};

var putRequest = new PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest
{
    BucketName = "yourBucketName",
    Configuration = bucketLifecycleConfiguration
};

var policy = await client.PutLifecycleConfigurationAsync(putRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the LifeCycleFilterPredicate to be a new LifecycleTagPredicate to use tags. If you want another rule for prefix also, you can add multiple rules to the Rules collection. There are [some good examples here with multiple rules](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/simplify-your-data-lifecycle-by-using-object-tags-with-amazon-s3-lifecycle/) in XML, but they may still be helpful in understanding the structure.

```
var lifeCycleConfiguration = new LifecycleConfiguration()
    {
        Rules = new List<LifecycleRule>
        {
            new LifecycleRule
            {
                Id = "Delete one day old objects",
                Filter = new LifecycleFilter()
                {
                    LifecycleFilterPredicate = new LifecycleTagPredicate()
                    {
                        Tag = new Amazon.S3.Model.Tag(){Key = "OneDayExpiry", Value = "true"}
                    }

                },
                Status = LifecycleRuleStatus.Enabled,
                Expiration = new LifecycleRuleExpiration()
                {
                    Days = 1
                }
            }
        }
    };
```